# strstr() in C and uninitialized values

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind, realloc

I need some help with `char*` initialization and `strstr` in C. This is the general issue:

I have a function `func1`, which concatenates strings from a `char** arr` until a semicolon is seen:

```
char * func1(int *i,int len,char **arr,char *path) 
{
    (*i)++;
    char* str = malloc(1);
    memset(str, 0, 1);
    for (; *i < len; (*i)++)
    {
        char* currExp = arr[(*i)];
        size_t currExpLen = strlen(currExp);
        size_t stringLen = strlen(str);
        
        if (strcmp(currExp, ";") != 0 )
        {
            if (currExp[currExpLen-1] == ';')
            {
                currExp[currExpLen-1] = '\0';
            }
            str = realloc(str, (stringLen + currExpLen) * sizeof(char)+2);
            sprintf(str, "%s %s", str, currExp);
        }
    }
    str = replaceBrackets(path,str);
    
    return str;
}
```

This function replaces a substring in `str` with the string `path`.

```
char* func2(char *path,char *str)
{
    char *t1 = str,  *t2 = str;
    size_t pathLen = strlen(path);
    
    while ((t1 = strstr(t2, "char")) != NULL)
    {
        size_t rplcIndx = t1 - str;  
        size_t stringLen = strlen(str);
        str = realloc(str, (stringLen + pathLen+1)*sizeof(char));

        memmove(&str[rplcIndx + pathLen], &str[rplcIndx+2], stringLen-rplcIndx-2);
        memcpy(&str[rplcIndx], path, pathLen);
        
        t2 = &str[rplcIndx+pathLen];
    }
    return str;
}
```

The issue is that valgrind gives an error basically saying that strstr might be using an uninitialized value. To rectify this, I'd have to do something like `char* str = "hello world";`, but then I can't `realloc`, which is an issue.

I have tested my program with random strings and the issue is the fact that valgrind is treating `str` as uninitialized, but I just don't know how to initialize it without getting rid of the ability to realloc. Any suggestions?

The error is:

```
==14356== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==14356==    at 0x4C29313: strstr (in path)
==14356==    by 0x401983: func2 (in path)
==14356==    by 0x401B06: func1 (in path)
==14356==    by 0x4013D7: main (in path)
==14356== 
==14358== Syscall param execve(argv[i]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
 at 0x4ECFCB7: execve (in path)
==14308==    by 0x4E6A76C: do_system (in path)
==14308==    by 0x4013ED: main
```

Edited: Added in the actual functions, changed names and such.

Comment: It looks like it is complaining because valgrind doesn't know if the str argument is initialized (going into func2).  Can you try something like `char *t2 = malloc(1); t2 = str;` and see if it complains?

Comment: Also, avoid using `str = realloc(str, ....);` -- if it fails, `str` will be set to `null` and you'll have lost your pointer to the memory that was originally allocated to it.  This is a classic memory leak.

Comment: Your problem is probably caused by incorrect null-terminating of the strings, but that can only be diagnosable if you post the whole code of func1(), and the error message from valgrind.

Comment: Your code is simplified too much. There's no way to figure out what happens from what you provided. For example, you use the return of `func2` to override the original value of `str`. This is important. But there's no way to see what `func2` returns. What is it `func2` returns and why are you overriding the old value of `str` with it?

Comment: I would guess that this is actually the problem. You original value of `str` is perfectly initialized and valgrind has no issues with it. It is later when you obliterate the original value of `str` and replace it with some garbage returned by `func2` the problems begin. Post the full code of `func2`.

Comment: In any case, even if this is not the main issue, the fact that you are overriding the value of `str`, which is the only pointer to some dynamically allocated memory, doesn't look good. Did `func2` deallocate that memory? If not, then by modifying `str` you lost access to that memory, i.e. leaked it. Was that your intent?

Comment: I edited in the actual functions. I don't think I'm losing the value because I always realloc() as opposed to creating a new string, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see is that func2 does no error checking. Whether valgrind is noticing this, or complaining about something else, I'm not sure.

If you know that in all use cases func2 will *never* be called with `std == NULL`, then you don't *need* error checks. But valgrind can't know that, even if it is true. Does a check like:

```
func2(str, line)
{
    char * t1 = str, * t2 = str;

    if (str == NULL) return;

    ...
}
```

help at all?

Comment: This is unlikely. Valgrind doesn't care whether you have any checks in the code or so, since it doesn't analyze the code at all. In fact, it only reports events (such as uninitialized data use, null/dangling pointer reference, etc.) that happen at run-time in a particular run.

Comment: If valgrind is complaining about an uninitialized value being used, checking for such errors should prevent that from occurring, thus (somewhat indirectly) fixing the issue.

Comment: ... except that you cannot check for uninitialized data in C. If it were null dereference, valgrind would say so; the fact that it reported uninitialized data indicates the error lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that valgrind notes that:

```
str = realloc(str, ....); //this is within the loop
```

can set `str` to NULL (if `realloc()` fails).

See if something like the following makes Valgrind happy:

```
char* tmp = realloc(str, ...);
if (!tmp) {
    abort();  // or some other error handling
}
str = tmp;
```